# Count files in a folder and subfolders with specific extension (.mp4) from the command line

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

I'm looking for a batch or any type of script (CMD/POWERSHELL) that can count files from folders and subfolders with directives.

My files structure is:

> C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\TASK\YEAR-MONTH\TaskID\MP4

I need to count the files in every `MP4` folder. I tried few scripts that I found around but nothing helps since it counts every single `.mp4` in every subfolder and that's not the number I'm looking for.

The current script I'm using:

```
dir /b *.mp4 /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > tmp && set /p count=<tmp && del tmp && echo Videos Found: %count%
```

The batch file should be dropped in the YEAR-MONTH folder and count everything from the MP4 subfolder inside the TaskID folder.

Note: There are 100+ TASKID (Real case when `task id` is actually `task id: 3130`) structures (`3130/mp4/`) <- I need to count `.mp4` files in this subfolder going inside every task folder.

I know this is overcomplicated and I would be happy if someone can pull this off!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will gather all the mp4 files in subdirs of the dir that the script is in ... and then filter out any that are NOT in a subdir named 'mp4'.

the `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable is the dir that the script is started from. drop it into the dir you want to work from and it will do as you described ... get the file count for the mp4 files in the mp4 subdir of the dir that the script is in.

if you want to be able to run the script from any location & give it the target dir, then things will need to be set up with a parameter for that. [*grin*]

```
$Filter = '*.mp4'
$StartInDir = $PSScriptRoot
$TargetSubDir = 'mp4'

$MP4_FileCount = @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $StartInDir -Filter $Filter -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Directory.Name -eq $TargetSubDir
        }).Count

$MP4_FileCount

pause
```

Comment: You are the MVP!

Comment: @ZEED - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Comment: call me noob, but how to add another parameter for example .jpg in $Filter =

Comment: @ZEED - you can't put multiple filters in the `-Filter` parameter. instead, use the `-Include` parameter - but DO NOT use both. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

A single line PowewrShell script:

```
"Videos found: {0}" -f (Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\TASK\YEAR-MONTH\TaskID\MP4 -Filter *.mp4 -File -Recurse).Count
```

The proper way in a batch file to process the output of other commands is
wrapping in a `for /f` not using tmp files.

```
@Echo off
For /f %%C in ('
dir /b /s "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TASK\YEAR-MONTH\TaskID\MP4\*.mp4" 2^>nul ^|find "" /v /c
') Do Echo Videos found: %%C
```

Comment: can i replace TaskID with * or something since i have 100+ folders every month

Also this is right "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TASK\YEAR-MONTH\TaskID\MP4\*.mp4" But, i need the batch file to be droped in YEAR-MONTH folder and start counting

Sorry if i wasnt clear enough in the first post, but seems lie this is the right direction im looking for. 

Edited the first post, im really sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.yaml -File -Recurse).Count
(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.yml -File -Recurse).Count
```

Comment: or `(ls -R -File -Filter *.yaml).Count`